# ArcGIS find all polygons that intersect with more that one polygon from another layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, intersection, overlapping-features

I have two layers with polygons. I want to find those polygons from first layer that intersect with more that 1  polygon from second layer and find those intersected polygons ID numbers: 1 from first layer and all from second layer, that intersect with it. I do not need polygons from first layer that have no intersection or intersect only with 1 polygon from second layer.

Is it possible by using ArcGIS to achieve this? Maybe somehow by selection only needed polygons or by joining all intersected polygon numbers from second layer to the first layer properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [Spatial Join GP tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) for this.

- `Target features`: study areas (green solid polys);
- `Join features`: tracts (red color)

Choose `JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY`. All other options - default. This is what you will get:

[image]

Study area 3 (TARGET_FID field) intersects tracts 9 and 36 (JOIN_FID field). Study area 4 doesn't intersect any, hence JOIN_FID = -1.

In case you would like to get some custom representation of this information, it's easy to do with Python to get something like this:

```
{3:(9,36), 2:(36,35), 1:(24,)}
```